# Connecting to Pervasive 11 with Odbc

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

For a client I had developed years ago an application that uses an existing database on Pervasive 10.  The database itself is used by a propriety application.   After a full server re-install Pervasive 11 was installed and somebody did a migration. I am not sure what exactly was performed but I do observe that the propriety application actually is working, so the connection to the Pervasive DB works.

The objective is to get the ODBC connection working again.

My observations so far:

- When I login in the control center I notice two main items, a Local Client with a MicroRouter and server instance containing three databases (DEFAULTDB, DEMODATA, TEMPBDB).   I have the impression that the customer database is missing here.

  - When I open the Software Monitor I notice that the MicroRouter is active and points to local .btr files which look like the tables from the database .

How can I have a ODBC connection pointing to the database?  Normally the DSN references the database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect through ODBC, you need the data files and DDFs (FILE.DDF,FIELD.DDF, and INDEX.DDF at a minimum).  Once you have the DDFs that describe the data files, you can create a Database in the Pervasive Control Center.  When creating the Database, you can select the option to create an ODBC DSN.
You should be able to right click on the "server" in the Control Center and select New Database. From there, you'll set the Database Name and set the Dictionary (points to the DDFs) and Data Path (points to the data files,usually the same directory where the DDFs are).

Comment: If it solved the problem, please accept the answer.  More information about accepting answers at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.